# Illegal Characters in Parquet file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet

I recently got data from Google Analytics (GA) and wanted to store the data in AWS as parquet file.

When I wanted to preview the file in the WebUI I realised it gives me an error.

I took me a while to realise that the column "pagePath" coming from GA is the reason for this as I am able to preview data once I remove the column.

I can´t share any data but is there any "illegal" characters that lead to failures?
I have >10k unique page paths and I can´t just figure out what the problem is.

Comment: You can try a test run where you remove all special characters. If that works, repeat, adding one special character at a time.

Comment: I’m not a parquet expert but I highly doubt it. To me it seems more likely that the file has been corrupted. Is the data stored in “hive” mode, if so, one or more files make up each column and it’s possible to lose one column without losing the whole file. I’d check to see if you can read the file directly, e.g. with a parquet library not a gui.